# Using inputs both in utf8 and latin1

Tags: input-encodings, french

#### Issue

I am writing a document in `utf8` but I have to include some files encoded in `ISO-8859` which are crashing my build.
Indeed, I am using `[utf8]{inputenc}` which works great for all my files but does not recognize characters from that one `latin1` file.

I tried switching back and forth between `\inputencoding{latin1}` and `\inputencoding{utf8}` but, I get some errors when including an `utf8` file with special chars afterwards (though it works if the file contains no such character but I does with or without switching the encoding back to `utf8`).

#### Setup

- `utf8-basic.tex`: `utf8` text file with no special chars (`\lipsum[1]`);
- `utf8-special.tex`: `utf8` text file with special chars ("é è à î ô â ê ï ç ù");
- `latin1.tex`: `ISO-8859` text file with special chars ("é è à î ô â ê ï ç ù").

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\input{utf8-special}
\input{utf8-basic}
% \inputencoding{latin1}
\input{latin1}
% \inputencoding{utf8}
% \input{utf8-basic}
% \input{utf8-special}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a test case we can run, unless the problem arises if the input files are just exacty the text shown. setting inputencoding as you show  should work in simple cases, but if there are section headings for example the table of contents handling can get tricky. Given that any editor and several command line tools can easily convert the encodings it is much easier just to arrange that all the files are utf8, even if that means running a script that copies/re-encoded latin1.tex to latin1-utf8.tex each time. (if you have a requirement to edit that part in latin 1)

Comment: Most modern  TeX editors can convert to UTF8. Which one do you use?

Comment: @David Carlisle The respective files are exactly as described.

Comment: @Bernard The aim is to automatize a process so I can/want not re-encode the files manually.

Comment: With a script. Are there so many files to convert anyway?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I only say "french"

Comment: @Bernard This is definitely the solution I am leaning towards, but I would like to understand why simply specifying the encoding does not work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the problem are the catcode changes of frenchb.ldf: It makes the colon active. \inputencoding{utf8} reads in utf8.def and this contains definitions which rely on the colon to have catcode "other". You can avoid the problem by using \shorthandoff:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\input{utf8-special}

\shorthandoff{:}
 \inputencoding{utf8}
\shorthandon{:} 

\input{utf8-special}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Il est bon que nous parlions français:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oui ça aide de connaître des langues étrangères ;-). Mais ici c'est plus important de savoir quelque chose sur les \catcode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wow ! Merci beaucoup pour votre aide.